# .htaccess rewrite resulting in 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create search engine friendly URLs with the following .htaccess and it is directing to a 404 error page no matter what I try.

This is on a Host Gator shared account, if it makes any difference. The directory is (document root)/blog, the .htaccess file is located in the directory "blog."

Example URL would be `http://examplesite.com/blog/category/announcements`.Here is the .htaccess file contents:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?category=$1
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: you path starts with "blog", but your rewrite rule starts with "category"

Comment: The .htaccess is in the directory "blog".. I also attempted to place it in the document root.. everything seems to result in 404. Are you saying it should be `^blog/category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?category=$1`

Comment: nope, just change `/$` at the end to `/*$` to account for the optional trailing slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/*$ index.php?category=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: note the /* at the end to account for the optional trailing slash

Comment: This worked without the R=301 and without `blog`, since the .htaccess file is already in the `blog` directory, revise and I'll select as answer. Thanks :) I really need to brush up on .htaccess files

Comment: The R=301 causes 404 errors again.. in fact, I just tried it again, and now it is broken again. Perhaps it takes a few minutes to switch back? Frustrating.

Comment: It appears that, after receiving a 404 once, every subsequent time that exact URL is used it will result in an error. `http://example.com/blog/category/General` generated a 404 error when I tried `[R=301,L]` and still does even after removing it, but `http://example.com/blog/category/general` does not. Also, the URL changes to `http://example.com/home/username/public_html/blog/index.php?category=General` on the 404 error.. interesting. Any idea?

Comment: When I enter the 301 I receive an error, tested on multiple machines and browsers

Answer (score 0):

Forget the preceeding slash?

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /index.php?category=$1
```